# How can I handle async exceptions using System.Net.Http.HttpClient with my integration tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I'm running a suite of integration tests that use `System.Net.HttpClient`.  Most of our "act" sections in these tests use this general format:

```
// Arrange
// Do some stuff

// Act
var download = _client
    .GetStringAsync(testUrl)
    .Result;

// Assert
// Does "download" contain what I expected?
```

However, running these tests intermittently yields something like this:

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : A task was canceled.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
```

I realize using `HttpClient` is meant for kicking off things async and isn't a perfect fit for our integration test scenarios where we always tell it to wait.  So this leads me to two questions that are somewhat related:

1. Is using `HttpWebRequest` / `HttpWebResponse` more appropriate for this scenario?
2. Even if it is, what's the best way to work with `HttpClient` to handle errors on requests kicked off asynchronously?

Comment: Why are you doing this asynchronously to begin with?  Seems like you'd want to do it synchronously...so I'd say yes to question #1.  For question #2, I'd increase the `Timeout` property of the HttpClient class, unless you need to test responsiveness within a certain timeframe.  Either way, I'm not sure why async would be better suited for unit testing...

Comment: Httpclient only provides async methods. OP is correctly converting them to synchronous calls by calling Result on the task. this also strictly speaking means that this is not an async exception, its a synchronous exception thrown after blocking on "Result". i'd try increasing the timeout

Answer (score 4):

As the previous commenters suggested, your connection is probably timing out.  You can set the timeout with `_client.Timeout = timeoutInMilliseconds` before making the GetStringAsync call.  However, if it is currently the default (100 seconds) then my guess is that the remote server you are testing against is actually down when this occurs.

More information on the timeout property can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`System.AggregateException` comes from exceptions that happen in a task run synchronously.  Using async tests allow the runner (in my case, NUnit) to decompose the task and get at the real exception.  So what the above code should've looked like is this:

```
[Test]
public async Task DownloadContainsWhatIExpected()
{
    // Arrange
    // Do some stuff

    // Act
    var download = await _client
        .GetStringAsync(testUrl);

    // Assert
    // Does "download" contain what I expected?
}
```

Using `async Task` in the method signature and then `await` on the asynchronous calls is the best way to execute these sorts of tests.

Comment: Exactly right! I just assumed that unit test frameworks weren't compatible with async/await and I was using .Wait() and .Result.  Thanks for setting me straight!